# Converting date uploaded as a factor to date

Tags: r, as.date

Trying to convert a column in my data frame to a date-time. The data has been uploaded as a factor in the format `'August 18, 2020 11:42'`.

I have tried using as.Date with the format:  `as.Date(calls$date_time, "%B %d, $Y %H:%M")`

but it returns `NA`

How can I fix this as.Date to give a date-time output?

Answer (score 3):

We could use `mdy_hm` function from `lubridate` package after converting factor to character:

```
library(lubridate)

a <- as.factor("August 18, 2020 11:42")
mdy_hm( as.character(a))
```

Output:

```
[1] "2020-08-18 11:42:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `%Y` instead of `$Y`, also change to `as.POSIXct` if we need date time instead of just `Date` class

```
as.POSIXct(str1, format = '%B %d, %Y %H:%M')
[1] "2020-08-18 11:42:00 EDT"
```

i.e. in the OP's code

```
as.POSIXct(calls$date_time, "%B %d, %Y %H:%M")
```

---

This would be easier i.e. if we use `anytime/anydate` from `anytime` (without having to deal with typos)

```
library(anytime)
anytime(str1)
[1] "2020-08-18 11:42:00 EDT"
```

`anydate` converts to `Date` class

#### data

```
 str1 <- 'August 18, 2020 11:42'
```